# Google Maps API timeout for "Oklahoma City, OK" and similar cities

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I see a (mostly) consistent timeout for these cities. There's a very curious pattern:

- Oklahoma City, OK
- Kansas City, KS
- Iowa City, IA
- Maryland City, MD

The first two are consistent, the latter two works sometimes. Other cities like New York City, NY works consistently.

```
>>> gmaps.geocode('Oklahoma City, OK')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/erikbern/mortgage/geo/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googlemaps/client.py", line 356, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/erikbern/mortgage/geo/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googlemaps/geocoding.py", line 68, in geocode
    return client._request("/maps/api/geocode/json", params)["results"]
  File "/Users/erikbern/mortgage/geo/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googlemaps/client.py", line 239, in _request
    extract_body, requests_kwargs, post_json)
  File "/Users/erikbern/mortgage/geo/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googlemaps/client.py", line 239, in _request
    extract_body, requests_kwargs, post_json)
  File "/Users/erikbern/mortgage/geo/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googlemaps/client.py", line 239, in _request
    extract_body, requests_kwargs, post_json)
  [Previous line repeated 7 more times]
  File "/Users/erikbern/mortgage/geo/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googlemaps/client.py", line 203, in _request
    raise googlemaps.exceptions.Timeout()
googlemaps.exceptions.Timeout
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/77891715) first reported on April 11. Google is still working on it. You can star the issue on the Issue Tracker to get updates from Google's engineers

#### Update

The bug was resolved on April 20, 2018.